# Problema MAVEN DEPENDENCIAS PROBLEMA SPRING BOOT

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, boot

porque me salen todos estos errores a la hora de crear mi proyecto en Sprint boot, agradecería su ayuda, me sale en esa linea y también en las dependencias , anexo imagen de los errores

[image]

Comment: Pues porque no tienes esos artefactos en tu repositorio local. Ejecuta maven install sobre ese proyecto y se descargarán y desaparecerán esos problemas.

Comment: @RubioRic gracias funciono

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clic derecho sobre el proyecto -> run as -> maven install
Es una buena opción con la información que proporcionaste.
Otra sugerencia: Usar Spring Tool Suite, es casi igual a eclipse pero tiene una gestión de dependencias muy práctica.

Answer (score 0):

puede ser por alguno de estos problemas:(ojo que estas instrucciones de pasos
son para MAC, para windows mismas instrucciones diferentes pasos)
1 checa que las dependencias q estas subiendo no tengan ningun vulneravilidad.
2 intenta actualizar tu proyecto. has click derecho en tu proyecto ve a MAVEN -> updated project
3 intenta hacer clean tu proyecto. dale un click a tu proyecto luego ve a project-> Clean (haz checkbox tu proyecto) y dale al clean button
4 no tiene los permisos para agregar licencias como adm. dale click a pom.xml ->file -> properties->en la opcion owner dale click a las 3 casillas ReadWriteExec. ->aply ->aplyandclose

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).